# How to get late good response while using spring integration BarrierMessageHandle for TCP based communication

Tags: spring-integration

I am using Spring integration for TCP client where I have used TcpNioClientConnectionFactory along with TcpSendingMessageHandler and TcpReceivingChannelAdapter. I am using BarrierMessageHandler so that http thread can be put on wait till TCP communication gets completed which is working fine as expected. But in certain case when the TCP response is delay, suspended thread timedout and complete its execution and post to which TCP response message has been received. In such BarrierMessageHandler trigger method does not pass such message to client as shown in code below. Is there any way BarrierMessageHandler can notify the client about late good reply along with its response message.

```
    SynchronousQueue<Message<?>> syncQueue = createOrObtainQueue(key);
    try {
        if (!syncQueue.offer(message, this.timeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)) {
            this.logger.error("Suspending thread timed out or did not arrive within timeout for: " + message);
            this.suspensions.remove(key);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean by "notify the client". By definition, the client has timed out and there is no longer a client to "notify".

However, I think we should add a discard channel to the handler and send late triggers there, so users can take some other action when this condition arises.

I opened a [JIRA Issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-4129) for this feature.

Comment: Yeah that's what I meant to have some handler to process late good response.